# Operation between 2 arrays for many rows based on date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset df_1 that looks like this:

| date | stock A | stock B | stock C | stock D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-11-01 | 4 | 8 | 14 | 30 |
| 2020-11-10 | 0.4 | 0.6 | 0.8 | 0.2 |
| 2020-11-30 | 6 | 10 | 20 | 35 |
| 2020-12-01 | 6 | 10 | 20 | 35 |
| 2020-11-31 | 8 | 12 | 25 | 0.1 |

And a second dataset, df_2:

| date | output1 | output2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11/2020 | stock A,stock B | stock C, stock D |
| 12/2020 | stock B,stock D | stock A,stock C |

I want to, for every output in df_2, compute the return for each month. An expected result for this example is df_3:

| date | output1 | output2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11/2020 | stock A: 50%, stock B: 25% | stock C:42.8% , stock D: 16.6% |
| 12/2020 | stock B: 20% ,stock D: 14.3% | stock A: 33.3% , stock C: 25% |

In the df_3, I do not need the result to be displayed with a comma separator, however, I need later to be able to plot everything in a graph with time on the X axis and stock values (from df_3) on the Y axis.

Update 1: As requested, here is the constructor of my sample dataframes:
df1:

```
{'PETROLEO BRASILEIRO ON': {Timestamp('1990-01-10 00:00:00'): 0.0, Timestamp('1990-01-11 00:00:00'): 0.0, Timestamp('1990-01-12 00:00:00'): 0.0, Timestamp('1990-01-15 00:00:00'): 0.0}, 'WEG ON': {Timestamp('1990-01-10 00:00:00'): nan, Timestamp('1990-01-11 00:00:00'): nan, Timestamp('1990-01-12 00:00:00'): nan, Timestamp('1990-01-15 00:00:00'): nan}, 'BANCO SANTANDER BRASIL UNITS': {Timestamp('1990-01-10 00:00:00'): nan, Timestamp('1990-01-11 00:00:00'): nan, Timestamp('1990-01-12 00:00:00'): nan, Timestamp('1990-01-15 00:00:00'): nan}, 'ITAU UNIBANCO HOLDING PN': {Timestamp('1990-01-10 00:00:00'): nan, Timestamp('1990-01-11 00:00:00'): nan, Timestamp('1990-01-12 00:00:00'): nan, Timestamp('1990-01-15 00:00:00'): nan}}
```

df2:
obs: "losers" stands for "output1"

```
{'losers': {Period('1992-08', 'M'): ['AGRALE ON 1000', 'SIBRA ON', 'IGB ELECTRONICA ON', 'CMPH.ENGT.DE SAOP.A PN', 'INEPAR ON', 'ANTARCTIC MG PN', 'BRASPEROLA ON 1000', 'DHB INDUSTRIA E COMERCIO ON', 'FERRO BRASILEIRO', 'GRANOLEO PN 1000', 'ITACOLOMY PNB 1000', 'SID RIOGRAND PN', 'ANTARCTIC PB ON 1000', 'BUETTNER ON', 'COFAP ON', 'MAIO GALLO ON 1000', 'NAKATA ON 1000', 'SAM INDUSTR ON', 'SID RIOGRAND ON', 'TECELAGEM BLUMENAU SERIES B PN', 'TELEMAR N L PNB', 'TRANSBRASIL ON', 'AQUATEC QUIMICA PN', 'ANTARCTIC PB PNA 1000', 'POLIALDEN PN 1000', 'MICHELETTO ON 1000', 'BRAHMA PN 1000', 'ELUMA PN', 'TELESP ON 1000', 'TELESP PN 1000', 'BLUE TECH SOLUTIONS EQI S ON', 'CACIQUE CAFE PN', 'SALGEMA PNA', 'ANTARCT NORD PNA 1000', 'TEKA PN', 'ANTARC PIAUI PNB 1000', 'BRAHMA ON 1000', 'CTI.ELETR BRAS- ELETROBRAS SR.A PN', 'NACIONAL ON 1000', 'ANTARCTICA ON', 'ARNO PN', 'TEL B CAMPO ON 1000', 'MANNESMANN PN 1000', 'BANCO DO NORD ON', 'MANGELS PN', 'AGROCERES PN 1000', 'CHAPECO PN', 'COINVEST PN 1000', 'MENDES JUNIOR ENGENHARIA SERIES B PN', 'BANDEIRANTES ON 1000', 'MENDES JUNIOR ENGENHARIA SERIES A PN', 'METAL LEVE PN', 'NORD BRASIL PN', 'PARANAPANEMA PN'...
```

Update 2:
I found another way around, we can use df1 to compute the monthly returns, and I would end up with this:

```
df1 = (np.log(df1)) - (np.log(df1.shift(1)))   
df1.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
per = df1.date.dt.to_period("M")
g = df1.groupby(per)
df1 = g.sum(min_count=1) # monthly return table`
```

| date | stock A | Stock B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11/2020 | 0.5 | 0.25 |
| 12/2020 | 0.33% | 0.20 |

Now I need to combine this df with df2 for the desired output table, which must be easier.

Comment: what is the format of the date, DD/MM/YYYY? also the dates don't match up so from when do you take in to account the beginning of the stock price

Comment: `31/11/2020` does not exist :)

Comment: In df_1., the format is  DD/MM/YYYY
In df_2, the format is MM/YYYY
I have changed the dates.

Comment: Can you explain how do you find 50% for stock A in november for example, please? I mean 50% of what?

Comment: From df_1 we have that the price in the first day of the month is 4 and in the last day (30/11) it is 6. So the return is (6-4)/4 = 0.5 =50%

Comment: So the row 10/11/2020 is useless. You keep only first and last day in a month?

Comment: Basically, for each row of df_2, find the month start and month end rows in df_1 corresponding to the month in the date column of df_2,, and for each cell in the other columns in df_2 (output1, output2), for each stock in the cell, find the corresponding columns in df_1 and read the stock prices in from the aforementioned month start/end rows then use the month start/end prices to calculate the return. Populate df_3 by essentially replicating df_2 but with the addition of the calculated returns. NOTE: it's not clear what the dates in df_2 mean.

Comment: Thank you @constantstranger. I have corrected the date on df_2. They stand for the months November and December of 2020.

Comment: Corralien, you are right. The row 10/11/2020 is useless. I only wrote it to make clean that my dataset has not only the month beginning and close dates, but other days as well.

Comment: why not just have the date and one output column? that will definitely make plotting easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the index of `df1` is a `DatetimeIndex` and `df2` a `PeriodIndex`. So suppose the following dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp, Period

data1 = {'index': [Timestamp('2020-11-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-11-10 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-11-30 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-12-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-12-31 00:00:00')], 
         'columns': ['stock A', 'stock B', 'stock C', 'stock D'], 
         'data': [[4.0, 8.0, 14.0, 30.0], [0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.2], [6.0, 10.0, 20.0, 35.0], [6.0, 10.0, 20.0, 35.0], [8.0, 12.0, 25.0, 0.1]]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(**data1).rename_axis('date')

data2 = {'index': [Period('2020-11', 'M'), Period('2020-12', 'M')], 
         'columns': ['output1', 'output2'],
         'data': [['stock A,stock B', 'stock C, stock D'], ['stock B,stock D', 'stock A,stock C']]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(**data2).rename_axis('date')
```

First, clean your first dataframe:

```
# Compute percentage change
pct = lambda x: x.iloc[[0, -1]].pct_change().iloc[1] * 100
df1 = df1.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).apply(pct)

# Reshape your dataframe
df1 = df1.melt(var_name='stock', value_name='pct', ignore_index=False) \
         .to_period('M').reset_index()
```

At this point, your first dataframe looks like:

```
>>> df1
      date    stock        pct
0  2020-11  stock A  50.000000
1  2020-12  stock A  33.333333
2  2020-11  stock B  25.000000
3  2020-12  stock B  20.000000
4  2020-11  stock C  42.857143
5  2020-12  stock C  25.000000
6  2020-11  stock D  16.666667
7  2020-12  stock D -99.714286
```

Now, reshape your second dataframe:

```
# Reshape your dataframe after splitting stocks
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(', ?')) \
         .melt(var_name='output', value_name='stock', ignore_index=False) \
         .explode('stock').reset_index()
```

At this point your second dataframe looks like:

```
>>> df2
      date   output    stock
0  2020-11  output1  stock A
1  2020-11  output1  stock B
2  2020-12  output1  stock B
3  2020-12  output1  stock D
4  2020-11  output2  stock C
5  2020-11  output2  stock D
6  2020-12  output2  stock A
7  2020-12  output2  stock C
```

Finally, merge your dataframes together:

```
# Join your dataframes on date and stock columns
df3 = df2.merge(df1, on=['date', 'stock'], how='left')

# Compute some columns
df3['fmt'] = df3['stock'] + ': ' + df3['pct'].round(1).astype(str) + '%'

# Reshape your dataframe to get the final output
df3 = df3.pivot_table('fmt', 'date', 'output', aggfunc=', '.join) \
         .rename_axis(columns=None)
```

The final output:

```
                                 output1                         output2
date                                                                    
2020-11   stock A: 50.0%, stock B: 25.0%  stock C: 42.9%, stock D: 16.7%
2020-12  stock B: 20.0%, stock D: -99.7%  stock A: 33.3%, stock C: 25.0%
```

Comment: You already have `date` as index and have the `datetime64` dtype?

Comment: Please provide constructor of your sample dataframes: `print(df1.to_dict())` and `print(df2.to_dict())`

Comment: I am facing an error "date" right in the beginning, in the step "# Remove unwanted date, keep only first and last day of month". I am not running the first line because I have done it previously. At the moment, my index is "DatetimeIndex["dates" as YYYY/MM/DD). Should my datetime be the index, or it can be the cause of the error?

Comment: I already have date as index and have the datetime64 dtype.

Comment: I have added the  constructors in the post.

Comment: The problem can be that, since I only have working days  in my df1, it fails to find the first and last day of the month when there are in weekends, for example.

Comment: Ok I get it. Maybe, it's possible to extract the first and the last available days for a month? Is it an acceptable solution?

Comment: That is what I am attempting to do, but with no success until now.

Comment: I just an update in the question